# Spark_Apply For TM library is throwing an error

Tags: r, apache-spark, apply, tm, sparklyr

I want to use the capabilities of TM library in `sparklyr`.
I used the function `spark_apply()` for the same. However I get the following error

> Error: Unable to retrieve a spark_connection from object of class data.frame

when I run my code. 
 Below is my code snippet

```
myFunction <- function(sparkdataframe){ 
  inputdf<-collect(sparkdataframe)
  inputdf<-as.matrix(inputdf)
  inputdf1<-t(inputdf)
  doc<-Corpus(VectorSource(inputdf1))
  doc<-tm_map(doc,removePunctuation)
  data.frame(doc = sapply(doc, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(doc)
}

# Use spark_apply to run function in Spark
spark_apply(sparkdataframe,function(e) (myFunction(e)))
```

Comment: You might try loading the TM library inside of your function with library(TM). This should make the function available inside the closure and consequently in each of the worker nodes.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you try `collect` in the closure:

```
inputdf<-collect(sparkdataframe)
```

The object recieved by your function is a plain R `data.frame`. Remove this line completely and replace following one with:

```
inputdf<-as.matrix(sparkdataframe)
```

Comment: Hi @user Thanks. Followed the suggestion. But still throws an error becuase of TM library. The first two lines are working fine. Meaning i am able to read the sparkdataframe and get its transpose. When i start converting the matrix into corpus datastructure the function fails